# Using subquery for update in Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

Is it possible to use **subquery** when updating an `ActiveRecord`?

I have a `products` table with following columns

```
id    number_of_orders
1           3
2           3
3           2
```

and an `items` table

```
id    product_id
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         2
6         2
7         3
8         3
```

What I want is

```sql
UPDATE products
SET number_of_orders = (
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM items WHERE product_id = 1
)
WHERE id = 1
```

I have tried

```php
$subquery = ItemsModel::find()
    ->select('COUNT(id)')
    ->where(['product_id' => 1]);

ProductsModel::updateAll(
    [
        'number_of_orders' => $subquery
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1
    ]
);
```

and

```php
$product = ProductsModel::findOne(1);
$product->number_of_orders = $subquery;

$product->save();
```

but none of this going to work.

Does anyone have any idea about solving this problem?

**Conclusion:**

> Each of the two ways works very well after I updated to `yii 2.0.14`.

Comment: Which version of Yii you're using?

Comment: My version is `2.0.12.2`. I wonder if the newest version support this feature. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try update Yii to the last version. Since 2.0.14 all instances of [`yii\db\ExpressionInterface`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expressioninterface) (including `Query` and `ActiveQuery`) should be handled properly and generate SQL in similar way as `yii\db\Expression`. So all this should work in Yii 2.0.14 or later:

```
$subquery = ItemsModel::find()
    ->select('COUNT(id)')
    ->where(['product_id' => 1])

ProductsModel::updateAll(
    ['number_of_orders' => $subquery],
    ['id' => 1]
);

$product = ProductsModel::findOne(1);
$product->number_of_orders = $subquery;
$product->save();

ProductsModel::updateAll(
    ['number_of_orders' => new Expression('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM items WHERE product_id = 1')],
    ['id' => 1]
);
```

Last example should work also in earlier versions of Yii.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try. :)

Comment: You may also try second example - since Yii 2.0.14 `Query` should be treated same as `yii\db\Expression`, so it may also work.

Comment: Hi rob006. My product env have to use the stable version vendor. In my `composer.json`, it says `"minimum-stability": "stable"`. I can't update to the newest version of `yii 2.0.14`. Do you have any idea. Thanks very much!

Comment: @paul 2.0.14 is definitely stable. What command you're using to update? Maybe you need to use `--with-all-dependencies` switch?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated to the newest version of yii2. Each two of the two examples works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [count()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#count()-detail) to get number of records.

```
$itemCount = ItemsModel::find()
   ->where(['product_id' => 1]);
   ->count();

$product = ProductsModel::findOne(1);
$product->number_of_orders = $itemCount;
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this way. But I want this `sql statement` being executed in one shot instead of two separated statements. :)

Comment: @paul then use normal sql instead of activerecord with createcommand()

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer:

```
$model = ProductsModel::findOne(1);
$model->updateAttributes(['number_of_orders' => ItemsModel::find()->where(['product_id' => 1])->count()]);
```

or you can do

```
$query = Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand(sprintf('UPDATE %s SET number_of_orders=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE product_id=:id) WHERE id=:id', ProductsModel::tableName(), ItemsModel::tableName()), [':id' => $id, ])
        ->execute();
```

ps: if both tables are the same, you have to do:

```
$query = Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand(sprintf('UPDATE %s SET number_of_orders=(SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE product_id=:id) xxx) WHERE id=:id', ProductsModel::tableName(), ItemsModel::tableName()), [':id' => $id, ])
        ->execute();
```

Comment: `updateCounters()` would be a good choice here, more simple and straight forward. `+1`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam But it requires 2 queries instead of one. And `updateCounters()` will **add** count to old value instead of replace it. And 2 last examples will not work since table names will be quoted as values. In fact, this answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @rob006 thank you for your feedback. fixed response accordingly. Just wanted to show how to get the tablename.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: check out ->updateAttributes instead

Comment: Thanks. I would take this in consideration if there is no other way. :)

Comment: @rob006 this was the thing to be noted that i overlooked **updateCounters() will add count to old value instead of replace it** thanks for the heads up.